# Turn off samesite enforcement in chrome version > 80

Tags: google-chrome

Now that chrome 80 has implemented the samesite cookie enforcement - is there a way to turn that off?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can disable this behaviour via `chrome://flags`. Specifically, you can enter these two into your location bar:

- `chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies`
- `chrome://flags/#cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure`

Set both to "Disabled".

However, while this might be useful for dealing with sites that still need to update, I would not expect this to be a long term solution.

Comment: It's for re-enabling our development environments while we update our cookies.  Thank you!