# disable chrome blocking cookies without SameSite=None

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, samesite

Chrome is suddenly blocking cookies without sameSite attribute set as None. How to get around that during development. 
I am already using

```sh
"chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=S:/chromeTemp --enable-cookie-prompt
```

So I don't care about security during dev.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn off samesite enforcement in chrome version > 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60292036/turn-off-samesite-enforcement-in-chrome-version-80)

Comment: Thanks ! I couldn't find that question after searching so much.